# How to use a web-component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I have a working web-component made in vanilla js. The idea behind these components is that they're framework-agnostic. According to React's documentation, they can be used in React app by simply writing (https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html):

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <user-card
        name="john doe"
        avatar="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg"
      >
        <div slot="email">joe@gmail.com</div>
        <div slot="phone">(+45)98-08-87-086</div>
      </user-card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. The web-component looks like this:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<style>
.user-card {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    width: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.user-card img {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
}

.user-card button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
</style>
<div class="user-card">
    <img/>
    <div>
        <h3></h3>
        <div class="info">
            <p><slot name="email"/></p>
            <p><slot name="phone"/></p>
        </div>
        <button id="toggle-info">Hide info</button>
    </div>
</div>
`;

class UserCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.showInfo = true;
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("h3").innerText = this.getAttribute("name");
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("img").src = this.getAttribute("avatar");
  }

  toggleInfo() {
    this.showInfo = !this.showInfo;
    const info = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".info");
    const toggleBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toggle-info");
    if (this.showInfo) {
      info.style.display = "block";
      return (toggleBtn.innerText = "Hide info");
    }
    info.style.display = "none";
    return (toggleBtn.innerText = "Show info");
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot
      .querySelector("#toggle-info")
      .addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleInfo());
  }

  disconnedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#toggle-info").removeEventListener();
  }
}

customElements.define("user-card", UserCard);
```

How to make it work with React?

Comment: React needs a wrapper around every Web Component to handle DOM and Events; See: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/ for all problems with React